# Is there any way to redirect a flutter web app to an specific screen according the url specified?

Tags: flutter, web

I have a web application developed in flutter. I need when the user access to ex. myhosting.com the app redirects him to an specific screen. However if he types myhosting.com/admin he most be redirected to another screen.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborate what you are trying to do, this helps you to get more accurate answers.

If the user didn't cleared browser cache, then the latest version or modern browser will remember the authenticated user accessed this specific url in the past. So, the browser will render the desired url page easily.

I hope this helps you to solve the issue. if yes reply with what you tried and what worked for you. if not share how did you solved the issue.